# Squeak when I depress clutch in Honda Civic

Tags: honda, civic, clutch, noise

I have a 2008 Honda Civic and for about 2 weeks there is a squeaking sound when I depress and release the clutch while changing gears.

Do I need to oil something? It is very noticeable in the cabin, but I can't see where it is coming from if it can in fact be oiled.

What is it that needs attention? Does it have to be addressed right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some deeper research, I have found that the cause is a worn thowout bearing. I also see that if this is to get replaced, it is wise to spend a few more $$ and replace the clutch as well as the labor to get at the bearing is the same as clutch replacment. So I guess I will be replacing both.